# How do I tell the kernel which driver to use?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, kernel

My wifi is behaving strangely (not scanning, not connecting to networks) to remedy this I'm trying to install drivers from Intel. The device is an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205. The documentation wasn't very clear on how to install it. I downloaded the `iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode` file from [this Intel page](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm), and copied that ucode file to /lib/firmware directory. That's all the documentation that came with the file told me to do. The information on [this page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) is pretty much the same info I got with the ucode file from intel. There's some stuff about a firmware loader and kernel config file that I don't understand.

When I run `$ sudo lshw -c network` I find the following:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 34
   serial: a0:88:b4:30:4b:08
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-35-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:43 memory:c0500000-c0501fff
```

It looks to me that `driverversion=3.8.0-35-generic` means the kernel is using some generic Intel driver and not the one I just downloaded from Intel. Am I correct? and if so, how to I get the kernel to start using the new driver?

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded and installed firmware, not a driver. The driver, depending on the device ID, calls the firmware it requires. Your *lshw* shows that the driver is the usual kernel driver iwlwifi:

> driver=iwlwifi

It also shows the firmware version being used:

> firmware=18.168.6.1

Isn't that what you downloaded?

You might try the usual fix:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

If you are still having trouble, let's look for clues in the logs. With the ethernet detached and a reboot so we have a clean slate, try to connect and then run:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e etwork -e wlan | tail -n25 > wifi.txt
```

Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and paste the result here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

The firmware file you downloaded probably already existed in your system. Is yours the same as default?

```
md5sum /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
```

Mine reads 4b47db024c8a0cba872c3e98e907a378.

Sometimes, after hibernate, the driver doesn't reload. Try reloading it from the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

You might try this fix:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Add one line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot.

How does it work now?

Comment: Ok, so as you pointed out the firmware does look correct. I ran the commands you posted and gave it a reboot. The situation seems the same. I have to run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` just to get my router's SSID on the list. Then it just won't connect. It will try for a few minutes, ask me for the network key, try again, ask for key, and repeat this process until it gives up.

Sometimes it will connect without hassle. Why it works 1 time out of 10, I haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: I belive I have found a weird work-around. If I hookup via ethernet, then run a wifi scan and connect, it almost always connects to the wifi on the first or second try. But once I reboot, it's back to the same nonsense. A bit of a hassle, plus I won't be able to hookup with ethernet at the library or cafe or wherever else I may go.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I get the same checksum: 4b47db024c8a0cba872c3e98e907a378

Comment: Awesome. Now the paste, please.

Comment: Here's the log right after reboot, I haven't done anything yet: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6833475/). And here's the log moments after that when I did a wifi scan from the terminal and repeated failed attempts to connect to the network: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6833502/).

Comment: What do you make of this? _config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets')_  It certainly sees your network: wlan0: send auth to 30:46:9a:0e:95:61 (try 1/3) and then: wlan0: authenticated. What is the result of: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan?

Comment: I have no idea what 'no-secrets' means. It does see the network but it won't connect. the result of `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` is generally it will scan the area and automatically attempt to connect to "Caesar's Palace," (my router). It will ask me for the key, despite the fact it's already saved, fail to connect, ask for the key, and on and on until it gives up and stops.

Comment: Just got back from work where the wifi worked without issue. Still not connecting at home. On a whim, I did the following: disable wireless via settings panel. Then edit connections > delete entry for my router. Enable wifi. `iwlist wlan0 scan`. Enter passkey, and it worked. Here's the [last 30 lines of log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6836447/). Maybe you'll be able to glean some information from it, I don't understand much of it.

Comment: What does: sudo iwlist scan tell us? Pastebin, please. Your 30 lines show a perfect sequence. The question now is why it takes intervention to do so.

Comment: I just repeated the action I took last night (disable wifi, delete entry,enable, scan). Because the computer has been hibernating and lost the network again but it didn't work this time. So these "workarounds" I've been finding probably aren't workarounds at all, just coincidence. Here's the [output of iwlist scan](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6838308/) as you requested. It's a lengthy list so I only included the entry for my router.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't want to speak too soon but after a full 24 hours without a problem, I think I found the problem. I changed the SSID from "Caesar's Palace" to "CaesarsPalace." I thought, since linux doesn't really like apostrophes or spaces in file names, maybe that's was screwing up the wifi. Since I renamed it, I've connected every time without issue. Thank you so much for the help!